# Does Git LFS use different authentication logic to Git client?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-lfs

We use on-premise Azure DevOps and are just starting to trial Git LFS. I've installed the latest client (3.0.2) alongside my git (2.31.1.windows.1 installed by Visual Studio IIRC) and everything initially looked good when cloning a Git repo from DevOps that has LFS files.

However my local repo only has references to the LFS files and when trying to run commands like `git lfs pull` (or fetch, or pushing a new LFS tracked file) I get authentication errors relating to `http://<server>:8080/tfs/<collection>/<project>/_git/<repo>.git/info/lfs` - i.e. a subpath of our git repo URL.

Googling has shown other people with similar problems but not clear answer what is happening, or why, or how to fix it. I don't understand if it's a DevOps implementation issue, or a local client issue on my side.

I did come across discussion about Git LFS not using the same credentials or authentication types as Git, or maybe looking in a different place for them - note we are on-premises using HTTP not HTTPS, maybe this is a factor?

Comment: Git LFS has to connect to two separate servers: one for the large files, and one for `origin` or whatever other name you give to the host (e.g., GitHub) that stores the Git repository. (The large files *aren't in the Git repository*, which is how Git-LFS gets around size limits.) Each server—the LFS one, and the hosting one—has its own authentication methods and requirements. This is all true regardless of which LFS server you use and which Git server you use: they're two separate servers, even if they're on the same host. (But if they *are* on the same host, some things might be simplified.)

Comment: @torek this makes total sense, the one problem being we can't see how we're supposed to _provide_ the LFS authentication. We are brand new to LFS so it may be very simple but DevOps doesn't even seem to advertise where LFS files _are_ stored, until we got this error message.

Comment: I haven't used Git-LFS (other than some very brief experimentation once when we decided not to use it) so I'm not really sure myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git LFS uses a different HTTP and TLS library than the one in Git.  Git uses libcurl, and Git LFS uses the Go HTTP library.  As a result, the supported authentication logic is different, although both programs will use the Git credential helpers and other credential lookup logic.

Since you mention Azure DevOps, my guess is that you're using NTLM.  In 3.0, Git LFS removed NTLM because it had known bugs and nobody was interested in fixing them, and because it uses cryptography known to be insecure since 1995.  Azure DevOps is the only major site known to use NTLM, and the Git LFS maintainers asked if they'd like to be involved in helping maintain it, and they declined.

NTLM can be handled in one of two ways: via the `NTLM` authentication scheme or the `Negotiate` scheme.  The latter is also used by Kerberos, which both Git and Git LFS do support, and which is secure.  Currently, if you have NTLM set up to use `Negotiate`, Git LFS simply won't work, since it prioritizes `Negotiate` over `Basic`.  In the upcoming 3.1, expected out this month or next, Git LFS will fall back to `Basic` if `Negotiate` fails, so you'll be able to work even if you have NTLM enabled on your instance.

I strongly encourage everyone to get rid of NTLM because it's so insecure.  There's really no defensible reason to use it anymore: even Microsoft tells you to turn it off.  If you turn off NTLM on your instance, or switch to Kerberos, things should just work.  Otherwise, you'll need to wait for Git LFS 3.1 or explicitly set the authentication method to `basic` in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a lot to go on. I think this is a good reference to add: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4247. Do you know how/where one can change this at client level not to use `negotiate`?

Comment: You can try the `lfs.<url>.access` syntax [from the manual page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn).  If that doesn't work, you'll have to turn off NTLM (which you should do anyway) or wait for Git LFS 3.1.

Comment: Now that Git LFS 3.1.x (and even 3.2.x) is out, how should this be handled in the best way?

Comment: You switch to Kerberos on your instance.  That's what Azure DevOps recommends.